# How can I modify this shiny app example to conditionally display a color of bus on a map (depending on output of a model)?

Tags: shiny, data-science, shinydashboard, cran

I'm trying to understand Shiny apps in particular this example of the bus dashboard located at

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/086-bus-dashboard

I'd like to modify the update rule so colors are displayed depending on whether or not locations$Bearing >= 200.

I tried modifying the locations dataframe which has Bearing but can't figure out how to chnage the color on map when the leaflet map is updated. It looks like it may have something to do with color = ~dirPal(Direction)

````
     addTiles('http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/transport/{z}/{x}/{y}.png') %>%
     addCircleMarkers(
       ~VehicleLongitude,
       ~VehicleLatitude,
       color = ~dirPal(Direction),
       opacity = 0.8,
       radius = 16
     )```

where dirColors is defined at beginning of script 

dirColors <-c("1"="#595490", "2"="#527525", "3"="#A93F35", "4"="#BA48AA", "5" = "#BA48AA")
````

I'd like to basically add a color here but conditionally displayed only for buses where Bearing >= 200 in location dataframe.

```
 routeVehicleLocations <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$routeNum))
      return()

    locations <- vehicleLocations()
    anomalies <- locations[locations$Bearing > 200,]
    if (as.numeric(input$routeNum) == 0)
      return(locations)

    locations[locations$Route == input$routeNum, ]
  })
```

The rest of the app is fine but would like to overwrite the color if condition above is met (Bearing >=200). Eventually would like to replace this rule with my own model and own data sources.